# jquery works not properly on first click, but in fiddle it does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this js-code in my programm http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/JyfPg/1/ and it works just fine on fiddle. In my programm it's working on every second click. I'm loading the data for the People from a xml file in a partial view.

On the first click I get an empty space below the Person and on the second it fills with the information I want. When I clik on a second Person it first close the open one (which it shouldn't, as I want to have the same behaviour as in the fiddle) and then it opens the content from the last open one until I click again and then it updates...

My js:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPeople", function () {
   if ($("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
      $("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).remove();
   }
   else {
      var peopleCallID = $(this).attr("data-id");
      var urlDetails = siteRoot + peopleID + "/peopleDetails";
      $("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails);
      $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='" + $(this).data("href") + "'> <td colspan='5'>"
        + $("#" + $(this).data("href")).html() + "</td> </tr>"); 
   }
});
```

My html:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm active show" id="btnPeople" data-href="peopleInfos" data-id="@item.ID">
                    Details  </button>
```

I'm sitting on this now for quiet a while,
first my js wouldn't work, so I had to change it from

```
$(function () { $("#btnPeople").click("click", function () {
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnPeople", function () {
```

I'm really new to javascript and jquery, so I'm sorry if there is an easy answer to this.

I already got rid of all extra scripts and style sheets, so there is no conflict there.
And tried :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", "#btnPrintAgent", function() {
```

Appreciate every hint you can give me.

EDIT: Problem solved!

I changed my code to :

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnPeople", function () {
   if ($("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
      $("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).remove();
   }
   else {
      var peopleCallID = $(this).attr("data-id");
      var urlDetails = siteRoot + peopleID + "/peopleDetails";
                $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='" + $(this).data("href") + "'> <td colspan='5'>"
        + $("#" + $(this).data("href")).html() + "</td> </tr>"); 
      $("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails);
   }
});
```

and now it's loading like it should.

By changing

```
  $("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails);
```

into

```
  $("#"+peopleCallID).load(urlDetails);
```

and setting my html to

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm active show" id="btnPeople" data-href="@item.ID" data-id="@item.ID">
                Details  </button>
```

everything works as I wanted.

Thanks for all the help and getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function load() give you a trigger after load is performed. http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

so your code should be:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPeople", function () {
    if ($("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).is(":visible")) {
        $("tr#" + $(this).data("href")).remove();
    }
    else {
        var peopleCallID = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var urlDetails = siteRoot + peopleID + "/peopleDetails";
        $("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails, function() {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='" + $(this).data("href") + "'><td colspan='5'>" + $("#" + $(this).data("href")).html() + "</td> </tr>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't see you reply before posting mine. You're correct

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luca, I tried it. But when I did, nothing happened. Debugger showed me that peopleID is now "undefined"

Comment: I can't understand this way.. can you put the new code on plunker again and post the new link here, in a comment?

Comment: I'll try. 
Seems like until "var urlDetails = siteRoot + peopleID + "/peopleDetails";" everything works fine, urlDetails is set, but in $("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails, function() { the ID gets lost.

Comment: if you wanna test your request change your code to:

    $( "#peopleInfos" ).load( urlDetails, function( response, status, xhr ) {
        if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "error: ";
            alert( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
    });

Comment: did that as well, nothing happens. I really appreciate your answer as it makes sense to call a function after loading. 
and I don't understand why jquery won't load, I looked into fiddler web debugger: it finds the page.

Comment: your answer should be the right one.
But I'm going to need an other solution, as this will not work for me. But thanks for your help.

Comment: check the code inside the load function.. if there's an error probably it's there.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but if I'm not wrong, the .load() function work "asyncronous", thus, when after it you call

```
 $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='" + $(this).data("href") + "'> <td colspan='5'>"
    + $("#" + $(this).data("href")).html() + "</td> </tr>");
```

The data are not fetched yet, thus you're working with old data.
Try change the two lines like this, adding a callback funciton to be called after the load function complete

```
$("#peopleInfos").load(urlDetails, function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr id='" + $(this).data("href") + "'> <td colspan='5'>"
    + $("#" + $(this).data("href")).html() + "</td> </tr>"); 
});
```